# Are there any custom maps for BFBC2?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

Are there any custom maps for BFBC2? If so, how do you play them?

Comment: @Arda but I would like to add that its about Battlefield Bad Company 2

Comment: The [bad-company-2] tag implies that. Also, in the future, please check if there are existing tags which meet your question before creating your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

There are no community maps or mods for Bad Company 2.  EA/DICE has no plans to release mod/map tools and the servers are restricted.